# Should the bracket overloaded operator in C++ be declared as a const function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to implement a bracket [] operator for my custom Array class in C++. I have a couple of options:

(1) `Point& operator[](int index)` 
(2) `Point& operator[](int index) const` 
(3) `const Point& operator[](int index) const`

(3) I understand is required in case the user declares a const object.
However, for the general case (1, 2) should I be making the function const because the object is never modified in the function body?

Comment: Do you want to allow things like `a[0] = b`?

Comment: It depends entirely on your intention. Though usually it's not desirable to have `T& operator[](int) const`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I do. However, I thought const only protects the object from modification inside the function body?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it is not possible to have `T& operator[](int cost)` (assuming you return a reference to a member) because this causes compilation errors.

Comment: @RSahu, while the duplicate is correct, it doesn't address the fact that overload (2) makes the program ill-formed (and at least two people in this question considered that overload semantically valid).

Comment: @SergeyA I'll assume you meant to write `T& operator[](int) const`. You're right if, in your words, you *assume you return a reference to a member*. That's why I said it's *usually* not desirable. Because that's *usually* an applicable assumption.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you read my intentions correctly ) Usually it is impossible :), and when possible, it is likely not desirable.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, I would be careful with the word impossible. This *is* c++. For example, all it takes is some `mutable` member for some reason and suddenly it's possible. I don't know how you would end up in *that* situation, but impossible is it's own thing. I get your point though.

Comment: @SergeyA, I would advise agaist supporting (2) even though it is possible to support it syntactically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) is correct for returning a reference.

(2) needs to be non-`const` since you want to be able to modify class members *through* the returned reference.

(3) needs to be `const` so `[]` can be called on a `const this` or equivalent reference.

Writing `Point& operator[](int index) const` would cause unexpected behaviour as you'd be able to modify a class member via a reference. Your `Point& operator[](int index)` function code might not be modifying the object, but it allows other code to modify the object since it returns a non-const reference to a data member. So `Point& operator[](int index) const` is not something you can provide, and the compiler should not be accepting a const function that provides non-const access to a class data member.

You should instead provide a non-const version together with a const overload:

```
Point& operator[](int index);
const Point& operator[](int index) const;
```

Comment: `Writing Point& operator[](int index) const...` no, it doesn't cause unexpected behavior. It causes compilation errors.

Comment: Yeah, we do not know what implementation OP has in mind, but I can't see where the reference might come from for the program to be well-formed. A global or static member of the class seems the only possible option, but I do not think it is in line with general OP question.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yet another edit. I think that covers it.

Comment: It would also fail if you return `this->member_vector[i]` or anything of sorts.

Comment: @SergeyA: Indeed, unless that member was `mutable`. Probably going off piste here,.

Comment: @SergeyA, it is easy to support (2) from a synactic point of view using the Pimpl idiom. I can't think of a semantically valid reason to support it.

Comment: Bathsheba, agreed.

Comment: Added a couple improvements to the answer.